# Android: stay connected with shared preferences

Tags: java, android, authentication, sharedpreferences, logout

Hi I did an Android app with several activities and for login-logout phase I used the example of this link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_session_management.htm

I want to add a checkbox in login-phase that, when it is clicked the app remember the user also when he exits without logout, 
but when this checkbox isn't clicked the user access to several activities but when he exits without logout there is still the logout.
For this reason I changed the MainActivity in this mode:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private EditText username,password;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String name = "nameKey"; 
   public static final String pass = "passwordKey"; 

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private CheckBox check;



        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    username.setText("admin");
    password.setText("admin");
    check   = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

    sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(name))
            {
            if(sharedpreferences.contains(pass)){
                    if (check.isChecked()) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(this,com.example.sessionmanagement.
    Welcome.class);

                startActivity(i);
                    }

                else
                    {

        logout();
                }
            }

            }
        super.onResume();
        }
 public void login(View view){

            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String u = username.getText().toString();
        String p = password.getText().toString();

            if(u.equals("admin") && p.equals("admin")){

            editor.putString(name, u);

            editor.putString(pass, p);

            editor.commit();

            Intent i = new Intent(this,com.example.sessionmanagement.Welcome.class);

            startActivity(i);

            }

    else{

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ko", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        }


    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            return true;

        }

      public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
    this.finish();
        }



    public void closing() {

        finish();
        }



    public void logout(){

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences

    (MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();


    editor.clear();

    editor.commit();

    moveTaskToBack(true);

    this.finish();
        }


    }
```

and in file.xml

```
<CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:checked="true"
       android:onClick="onResume"
       android:text="CheckBox" />
```

This code doesn't work because when checkbox isn't checked there is directly logout, the user can't access to other activities. How can I write the condition when checkbox isn't checked?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you calling `onResume()` on the click event?

Comment: because I want that the operation to remain connected to happen after the OnPause of the app and for this reason I did the control in onResume(). Was I wrong?

Comment: I did not understand your logic behind that.

Comment: I want by clicking the checkbox the user remains logged in even after onPause app, while if the checkbox is not clicked there is logout